# Materialzed grid unknown number of items

Tags: jsx, materialize, css-grid

I'm using Mataralize css grid system. I'm inserting all the items I get from the backend in a grid, but I dont know beforehand how many items I'll get. Is there a way with materialize to dynamically add `.row` classed base on the number of items in an array? this is my workaround code, but its not easy to use, I'm looking for a easier simpler way:
first I'm spliting the array to smaller arrays of 3 items each (I want each row to contain 3 items):

```
let temporary;
  let chunk = 3;
  let newProdsArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i += chunk) {
    temporary = products.slice(i, i + chunk);
    newProdsArr.push(temporary);
  }
```

then I'm doing a nested loop in JSX

````
return (
    <section className="container">
      {newProdsArr.map((products, i) => (
        <div className="row" key={i}>
          {products.map((product) => (
            <ProductItem
              key={product.prodToken}
              product={product}
            ></ProductItem>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </section>
  );
``` is there a simpler way? or should use the flexbox modal (to be able to do ```flex-wrap``` ) and then insert as many products as there is dynamically
````

Comment: don't know why u using grid. flex-box do the trick. As u wrote flex-wrap would be perfect when u don't know b4 hand. it gives u more flexibility. Otherwise if you must to look Auto-Sizing attributes in CSS-Grid: like `auto-fill` and `auto-fit`

Comment: If the content is all the same height, you don’t need to output multiple rows. You can put an infinite number of cols inside a row, but you’ll run into issues if they have different heights. I’m that case, what I do in php is echo an opening row if the index is equal to 1,4,7,10 etc and a closing div before the end of the loop if equal to 3,6,9 etc. Stick with the grid if using Materialize and your styles will be more consistent.